# Read input file word by word

Tags: c++, function, file-io

I will first off say that yes, this is a homework assignment, but my teacher is really not too clear on how to do things.

I'm asked to, in c++, Write a function that will pass words from a file one at a time.  The function will calculate the word length and then print out TO SCREEN the word and its length on its own line.

The main will open your input file, read it word by word in a loop and then pass the word into your function for it to be printed.

I know how to open a file using fstream and all that, read it word by word, but not in a loop or a function by the void readfile () one. My problem here is putting everything together.

This is my program to open a file, get the length and display it in a parallel array

```
//declare parallel arrays

string words [MAXSIZE];

//open files
outputFile.open("output.txt");
inputFile.open ("/Users/cathiedeane/Documents/CIS 22A/Lab 4/Lab 4 Part 2/lab4.txt");


//inputvalidation

while (!inputFile.eof())
{
    for(int i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; ++i)
    {

        outputFile << words[i] << " " << endl;
        inputFile >> words[i];

    }
    inputFile.close();

}
for (int i= 0; i <= MAXSIZE; i++)

{   cout << words[i] << ":" << words[i].size()<< endl;
    outputFile << endl;
}

//close outputfile
outputFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, what of that do you know how to do?  Can you write a program that reads a file and prints it to the console?

Comment: yeah, i opened the file and it had three words on it, like hello my friend. to get each on its own line, i just did something like inputfile >> word cout << word << endl; 3 times :P

Comment: Can you post your program in your question?

Comment: I think you could get away with one string. Get it, find it's size, print it on a new line, continue until eof.

Comment: Thanks.  Why are you storing the words in an array?  Why not print out the word immediately after reading it, then throw it away afterwards?

Comment: How would you do that in a loop? Sorry, I'm really only into my 5th week of coding haha

Comment: Right now, you have two loops.  In the first loop, you read everything into an array, then in the second loop, you print out everything in the array.  Why not leave out the array, and print out each word as you read it?  That way, you only need one string -- and you can handle a file of any length.

Comment: how would i display the length and word side by side?

Comment: You already print out the word and its size side by side in the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

So basically your assignment is :

```
function read_word
  /* what you have to work on */
end

function read_file_word_by_word
  open file
  while not end_of_file
    word = read_word
    print word, word_length
  end
  close file
end
```

To read a word, you need to define what it is. Usually it's a bunch of letters, delimited by other characters that are not letters (whitespace, commas, etc.).

You could read the file character by character and store them when they are letters until you encounter some other kind of character. What you have stored is a word, and you can get its length quite easily.

Tip: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/ allows you to read a single character from a file.

Comment: ok, i'll try this out! just a  clarification though haha sorry. how would the loop for the while eof go? i'm not totally clear on how that works

Comment: and what is the function read_word? it seems i'm doing that in the second function.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void func(const string& word)
{
    //set field width
    cout.width(30);
    cout << left << word << " " << word.size() << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream ifs("F:\\tmp\\test.txt");
    if(ifs.fail())
    {
        cout << "fail to open file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    _Ctypevec ct =  _Getctype();
    for(char ch = 0; ch < SCHAR_MAX; ch++)
    {
        //set all punctuations as field separator of extraction
        if(ispunct(ch))
        {
            (const_cast<short*>(ct._Table))[ch] = ctype<char>::space;
        }
    }

    //change the default locale object of ifstream
    ifs.imbue(locale(ifs.getloc(), new ctype<char>(ct._Table)));

    string word;
    while(ifs >> word)
    {
        func(word);
    }

    ifs.close();
}
```

Comment: `while(!ifs.eof())` is just wrong.  Why not `while(ifs >> word)`?

Comment: in the code below this, it says word = read_word, how do you go about doing this?

Comment: @CathieDeane, you initially said you didn't want the exact solution. That's why our two answers invoke getWord(), or similar. Investigate what C++ function could get you an `std::string` from a file.

Comment: what do you mean by "word = read_word"?Am I misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 0):

Now that some time has passed since you asked the question, I would like to add that this could be answered in a quite small amount of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void printString( const string & str ) { // ignore the & for now, you'll get to it later.
    cout << str << " : " << str.size() << endl;
}

int main() {
    ifstream fin("your-file-name.txt"); 

    if (!fin) {
       cout << "Could not open file" << endl;
       return 1;
    }

    string word; // You only need one word at a time.
    while( fin >> word ) {
       printString(word);
    }

    fin.close();
}
```

A small note on `fin >> word`, this expression returns true for as long as there was a word read into the string. It will also skip any whitespace (tab, space and newline) by default.

Answer (score 0):

You'll obviously want to separate each word in to its own `string` index to store them in your array.  To separate each word, establish a break point like `char break = ' ';` Then, while your `IOStream` is reading the file, just add the words to the index using an iterator (i++)